# How do I set a BrowserField to fill the available screen space?

Tags: java, blackberry, browserfield

I have a BrowserField that is displayed on the main page of a BlackBerry application I am working on. It is intended to fill all the screen space below the header image. I haven't been able to find a way to do this so far. Does anyone have any suggestions for me?

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you look at using a custom LayoutManager, with it's size filling the screen. You could limit the first child in the manager to be the size of the image, then the rest of the size would go to the second child (in this case your BrowserField).

For further information, take a look at this link : [BlackBerry Support Forums](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Create-a-custom-layout-manager-for-a-screen/ta-p/442990)